# Angular Fullcalendar Resource label with DOM Events are only executed once after running getApi() associated methods

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm currently rendering some resources and events inside my Angular + FullCalendar app.

I have the next `resourceLabelDidMount()` method in the calendarOptions:

```
resourceLabelDidMount: (info) => {
      if (!info.el.classList.contains('section_item')) {
        // Activity Info
        let activityInfoElement = info.el.querySelector('.activity-info');
        activityInfoElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.showActivityDescription(info);
        });

        // Event Creation / Management
        let clickedElement = info.el.querySelector('.planificator');
        clickedElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
          this.showDialog(info);
        })
      }
    },
```

The problem is when I run the next code inside the `showDialog()` method (in this method I need to create one Event associated with this resource, and maybe any resource property must be changed - priority as example), I cannot execute the 'click' event, then the click is only executed once.

```
let resource = this.calendarRef.getApi().getResourceById(res.activity.id)
resource.setExtendedProp('priority', 1);
```

The resource is updated after I execute the previous code, but I'm not able again to run the click event associated with the `resourceLabelDidMount()` method and the `addEventListener` executed inside that method.